# "Ambiguous match found" when using FocusManager.FocusedElement

Tags: .net, xaml, focus, silverlight-5.0

I don't think I've ever had a compile-time error of `Ambiguous match found` - I associate it with runtime exceptions.

When I add a `FocusManager.FocusedElement` setter in my XAML I get the build error, no further detail. I've tried adding this attribute in a number of places (control root, the parent element, the target element), and in a number of controls, and for a number of targets.

Any suggestions on what to do now? Completely lost.

I'm also unable to set the focus to the target control in the code behind. I don't know if this is related...

Comment: Nope, I set the focus using the Tab Order property.

Comment: Had no idea why I was getting this error. Thanks for tying it to the FocusManager!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <util:SetFocusTrigger TargetName="SearchBox" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

More info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/222613/Setting-focus-on-a-control-in-Silverlight-using-XA